# JQL Query - Use a filter result in another JQL query

Tags: jira, jql

I have a JQL filter searching for epics fulfilling certain requirements.

Now i would like to do something like:

```
"Epic Link" in (filter= 22611)
```

I know one can use filters with AND etc, but this doesn´t seem to work.
Is this even possible or is there another way round?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested JQL calls are not (yet) possible in Jira. Atlassian have a feature request raised for this [here](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-21936).

You will need to accommodate the JQL with the AND operator in front.

Comment: I managed to solve my concrete case like this: 
fixVersion = yyy AND project = xxx AND type not in (Epic, Sub-task) AND "Epic Link" is not EMPTY AND issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("fixVersion = yyy", "is Epic of") ORDER BY status DESC