# How to evaluate multiple ANDs and ORs in JQL without parenthesis?

Tags: jira, jql

I have to document a query that someone wrote who is no longer with the company. The query is a JQL search in Jira. The person didn't use parenthesis and it's this huge glob of ANDs and ORs. I know it evaluates left to right, but in this case I don't really know what that means. I use parenthesis when I write such things.

Here is what the query looks like (I'm going to keep it general here.

Field1 = answer1 AND field2 = answer2 AND field3 = answer3 OR field4 = answer4 AND field5 = answer5 OR field6 = answer6 OR field7 = answer7 AND field8 = answer8

Let's take the first 'OR.'  I don't know if the first OR forces the first three things to group together, or if it's only ORing field3 and field4.

Then the same on the second OR. is it ORing only field6 and field7, or is it ORing everything before it and field7, or everything before it and everything after it?

The end goal is to try to add parenthesis and be able to walk my boss through what it really is saying.

The only things I've tried so far is lots of reading and googling.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to refer the evaluate as how its done in Excel function evaluator -- then I am sorry its not that easy here.

to understand multiple Logical operators in JQL on had to run the query

- by splitting the query into smaller ones (divide and conquer)
- analyse every result
- integrate them finally to get the full result.!

You can use nested JQL to get results from various queries.-- but this feature is in-progress with Jira - refer https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-21936

and this Stack overflow reference [JQL Query - Use a filter result in another JQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56100143/jql-query-use-a-filter-result-in-another-jql-query)

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation [here](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-core-cloud/docs/use-advanced-search-with-jira-query-language-jql/) :

You can use parentheses in complex JQL statements to enforce the precedence of operators.

For example, if you want to find all resolved issues in the 'SysAdmin' project, as well as all issues (any status, any project) currently assigned to the system administrator (bobsmith), you can use parentheses to enforce the precedence of the boolean operators in your query, i.e.

```
(status=resolved AND project=SysAdmin) OR assignee=bobsmith
```

Note that if you do not use parentheses, the statement will be evaluated left-to-right.

For your case could be better to surround all logical oparators with parentheses to clean up the mess.

Answer (score 0):

If the statement is evaluated left-to-right as indicated in the JQL docs, you can replace that query with this one:

```
(((((Field1 = answer1) AND (field2 = answer2) AND (field3 = answer3)) OR (field4 = answer4)) AND (field5 = answer5)) OR (field6 = answer6) OR (field7 = answer7)) AND (field8 = answer8)
```

Which reformatted is this:

```
(
  (
    (
      ((Field1 = answer1) AND (field2 = answer2) AND (field3 = answer3)) 
      OR 
      (field4 = answer4)
    ) 
    AND 
    (field5 = answer5)
  )
  OR 
  (field6 = answer6)
  OR 
  (field7 = answer7)
)
AND 
(field8 = answer8)
```

**Important note**: I can just about guarantee that the original query does not give the result that the original author intended. No one writes boolean logic in that way because, as you can see, it's impossible to read. So my advice is to guess what it was trying to do from context and re-build the query from scratch.

Comment: Warning! I was not able myself to find in the doc the evaluation order stated in this response, and apparently there is contradictory information here: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/What-is-the-order-of-operations-in-JQL/qaq-p/1468890